# Upgrade to Rails 4.0.5 results in uninitialized constant Surveyor::Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been using the surveyor gem within Rails 3.2.x without any issues in my project.

The gem defines modules that reside within the lib subdirectory of the gem.

Example

`lib/surveyor/helpers/surveyor_helper_methods.rb`

Then in my app/helpers directory I include the module and extend like follows.

`include Surveyor::Helpers::SurveyorHelperMethods`

This works fine in Rails 3, but within Rails 4 it results in the error Uninitialized constant Surveyor::Helpers.

As a test I copied the directory from the gem directly into my projects lib directory structure and this got rid of the error; so it seems the include is no longer looking at the gems' lib tree.  Moving all of the files directly up into my project isn't a good solution.  Is there another way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

in your helper , just include this file..so it will be something like

```
require 'surveyor/helpers/surveyor_helper_methods'
module UserHelper
 include Surveyor::Helpers::SurveyorHelperMethods
end
```

Comment: Then I just get the following error message instead. `uninitialized constant Surveyor::Helpers::SurveyorHelperMethods::AssetPipeline`

Comment: then do this `require 'surveyor/*'`

Comment: Ok; I see that requiring like this brings this in on a cases by case basis.  It seems I'm having a similar issue with my routes.  The gem specifies routes that should be picked up; these also do not show up in my routes now.  In Rails 3 these things were picked up automatically.  Is there some way to modify the load path or something similar to auto include these things form the gem?